# How do I use a variable in a grep with groovy?

Tags: groovy, grep

I need to grep for lines with bunch of names, say `clientLogin=a@yahoo.com`, `clientLogin=b@gmail.com` from a file.txt.

file.txt has junk which is `email=a@yahoo.com email=b@gmail.com`. I need to filter these out

Once I get these lines I need to grep for gmail and yahoo and get their counts

```
List l = new ArrayList{a@yahoo.com, b@gmail.com}
def gmail = ['sh','-c','grep "clientLogin="$l.get(0) file.txt' | grep gmail | wc -l ]
def yahoo = ['sh','-c','grep "clientLogin="$l.get(1) file.txt' | grep yahoo| wc -l ]
```

This doesn't work. How can I substitute the $l.get(1) value dynamically?

---

the problem is that ${l.get(0)} has to be inside the  " ", 
i.e.:

```
def gmail = ['sh','-c','grep "clientLogin=${l.get(0)}" file.txt' | grep gmail | wc -l ]
```

so that it will look like:

```
def gmail = ['sh','-c','grep "clientLogin=a@yahoo.com" file.txt' | grep gmail | wc -l ]
```

but `clientLogin=${l.get(0)}` doesn't produce the result. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't produce the result, at least when I tried it.

---

file.txt has lot of junk and a pattern something like:

```
Into the domain clientLogin=a@yahoo.com exit on 12/01/2008 etc..
```

hence I do

```
def ex = ['sh','-c','grep "domain clientLogin=$client" file.txt'| grep "something more" | wc -l]
```

that way I can chain the grep as I want and eventually land at the count I need.

I am not sure if I can chain the greps if I use

```
def ex = ['grep', "$client", 'file.txt']
```

thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5):

You're already using groovy, does using a regular expression that gives you your answer work?

```
def file = new File("file.txt")    
file.delete() // clear out old version for multiple runs
file <<  """
foobar clientLogin=a@yahoo.com baz quux   # should match a@yahoo.com
foobar email=a@yahoo.com baz quux
foobar email=b@gmail.com bal zoom
foobar clientLogin=a@yahoo.com baz quux   # should match a@yahoo.com
foobar clientLogin=b@gmail.com bal zoom   # should match b@gmail.com
foobar email=b@gmail.com bal zoom
"""

def emailList = ["a@yahoo.com", "b@gmail.com"]
def emailListGroup = emailList.join('|')
def pattern = /(?m)^.*clientLogin=($emailListGroup).*$/

def resultMap = [:]

(file.text =~ pattern).each { fullLine, email ->
    resultMap[email] = resultMap[email] ? resultMap[email] + 1 : 1
}

assert resultMap["a@yahoo.com"] == 2
assert resultMap["b@gmail.com"] == 1
```

That feels cleaner to me than trying to shell out to a process and working with that, plus it only will pick out the exact lines with "clientLogin=(email)" that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need the 'sh' and '-c'. I was able to get this to work:

```
def client = 'foo@bar.com'
def ex = ['grep', "$client", 'file.txt']

def proc = ex.execute()
proc.waitFor()

println "return: ${proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```

[Groovy's documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy) may also assist you with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need {}'s around the variable expression.  That is:

```
 "${l.get(0)}"
```

See [Groovy String](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1525-Strings) documentation for more information.

Full example:

```
List l = new ArrayList{a@yahoo.com, b@gmail.com}
def gmail = ['sh','-c','grep "clientLogin="${l.get(0)} file.txt' | grep gmail | wc -l ]
def yahoo = ['sh','-c','grep "clientLogin="${l.get(1)} file.txt' | grep yahoo| wc -l ]
```